# Remove Save As and Copy Video URL in Media Web Part

Tags: 2013, media-streaming

We are trying to add streaming Video capability in our SharePoint 2013 Site and what we already did is getting the Video from SharePoint URL.

Our problem is that we need to remove the `Save video as...` and `Copy video URL` when we right click in the video.

Is there an option or way to remove that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the whole right click menu (contextmenu) using `oncontextmenu="return false;"` attribute in your video tag but you cannot hide some of the options from the right click menu.